# What noise mean in accuracy-loss graphs (LSTM)?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am trying to train a LSTM model and I am also
plotting the graphs of train-test accuracy and train-test loss as you can see from the images I attached.
What concerns me is that the plots are noisy. From my understanding and please correct me if I am wrong noise means that I overfit my model and it doesn't learn. Am I right?
Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Comment: After certain epochs, the loss becomes constant. Try epochs=100 and different values of learning rate, momentum, decay, optimizers etc. btw, I don't think your experimentation is wrong as such.

Answer (score 0):

"Noise" doesn't mean overfit. When your validation loss is much higher than your training loss **or** when your validation accuracy is much lower than your training accuracy, we call that **overfitting**.

But for your situation, your training & validation accuracy is similar, your training & validation loss are similar too. Therefore, Your model is not overfitting.